# LifeUpdate on Database change Throws error

Tags: c#, signalr

I followed this [guide](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc#content), And i do manage to get it to post the value of my database but when it wont update the page when i change the content in the database.

So when I debugged the NotificationHub.cs These 2 lines throw an error.

```
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages, totalNewCircles, totalNewJobs, totalNewNotification);
```

The Error it throws is :

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' Occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task ' can not be implicitly converted to 'string'

Here is the SendNotification Code:

```
public string SendNotifications()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT NotificationNumber FROM [dbo].[NotificationStatus] WHERE UserID=" + "1";
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            try { 
            command.Notification = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);                
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                totalNewMessages = Int16.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["NotificationNumber"].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        }
    }
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
}
```

Hope someone can point out whats goes wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it's the database?  Try commenting it out and executing a hard coded value: `return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(3);`

Comment: When i run the page without debugger, It dont show any error and it does post the correct vallues of from the table. but when i update the database value it dont update that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages)` is a dynamic method and its return type is `Task`; this cannot be converted to a string, which is what you're trying to return from SendNotifications. So you need to change the signature, e.g:

```
public Task SendNotifications();
```